# Correct way to expose a cancellable Task API

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

If I want to expose an API which internally Schedules a sequence of Tasks that should be cancellable by the user.
e.g.

```
public ??? DoWork()
{
    Task t = new .... , myCancellationToken);
    return ???
}
```

What is the correct object to return for cancellation Control?
Is it CancellationTokenSource ?

```
public CancellationTokenSource DoWork()
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new ....
    Task t = new .... , source.Token);
    return source;
}
```

Should I return anything at all?
Should I just accept a CancellationToken as an arg and let the user create the token source if needed?

```
public void DoWork(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task t = new .... , token);
}
```

What is the most idiomatic way to deal with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I just accept a CancellationToken as an arg and let the user create the token source if needed?

This. But you should quite possibly return a `Task` as well, so that the user can observe when it's completed etc. This is amenable to async/await as well, of course.

You may also want to have overloads:

```
public Task DoWork()
{
    return DoWork(CancellationToken.None);
}

public Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
}
```

See the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for general conventions on this sort of thing.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if this should really be written as an overload, or instead as an optional `CancellationToken?` parameter that defaults to `null`.

Comment: To answer myself: I'm guessing that it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @StevenLiekens .Net itself uses overloads, not optional parameters. That tips the scales a bit in favor of overloads.

Comment: I prefer overloads for public APIs for versioning and reflection reasons, but for my app code I will sometimes use optional paramters (in this case, `CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()`).

Comment: Or `CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None`, @StephenCleary.

Comment: @StevenLiekens, as it is a matter of preference to wear clothes in the north pole or not. If you choose to wear clothes (overloads) you'll have to do some work. If you choose not to, it will look like it's less work but it isn't and you might dye.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: `CancellationToken.None` cannot be used as an optional parameter default value.

Comment: If it makes people using publicly exposed optional arguments, it's a win. When using optional arguments, the value will be hardcoded in the caller, thus @StephenCleary comment on versioning.

Comment: Yeah, @StephenCleary. I use it so rarely that I forgot optional arguments can't be used with properties because they aren't constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Async methods should return the Task. You will need the Task for syncronization purpose as well as for getting the result if you do not implement callback-Patterns with IAsync. If you mark the method with async and call it with await the result is unwrapped from the Task automatically.
Task is the point of interest in TPL. Do not create a new Task if you do not need to do it explicitle, prefer the static Run method instead.